# Unit Test Session doesn't show tests from new test class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, test-project

- VS2013 Update 5
- Created C# MVC Web Application project including a Test Project.
- Updated all packages...

I moved my Models namespace, all model classes and the ApplicationDbContext into a new class library, separate from the MVC Web App project.
I added a reference to the Test Project for this.

The Test Project shows a 'Controllers' folder and in that folder is HomeControllerTest.cs

I wanted to add tests for my Model classes, so I added a 'Models' folder and a very similar cs file for testing my models. The class and methods are public, and the appropriate attributes for the class [TestClass] and methods [TestMethod] are assigned

I added Tests for Insert, Get, Update and Delete for one of my models.

Everything compiles fine.

The Unit Test Sessions show no tests from this newly added class; see image...
I've restarted VS2013, cleaned solution, rebuilt...everything...except that which will make it work.

How do I get the newly added tests to be run-able via, or visible to, the Unit Test Sessions window??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing Resharper's cache? (Resharper > Options > Environment > General > Clear Cache).

I had a similar issue before and that was what worked for me. May be worth a try!

Comment: Thanks - I'll certainly give it a try

Comment: Well, that didn't work. I finally did get it to work though. I don't know if one thing affected the other, but I right clicked on the test project, and added a unit test - that didn't show. Then I deleted all tests in the Unit Test Sessions window (shown near the bottom) and then rebuilt the project. It now shows all test classes and test methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look in the Resharper Unit Tests section of the options menu there should be a tick box labelled "Enable Shadow Copies".

Unticking this option appeared to solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case selecting *Append all tests from [MyTestProhect]* context menu solve the issue:

[image]